# Live Update Searchable Database MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

Tony, the updated code shown below, it won't let me comment this so i've edited my previous post, this code below, doesn't return any results or errors, it just reloads the page. The only issue i can see with the code, is that i need to be able to search, by all table headers, Rating, Name, Area etc. I had a datatable script that live updated the tables to the result, but this doesn't work with the PHP table and i'm not sure how i'm meant to make it work with datatables, as i've never used it before:

```
updated code:

<html>
<head>
<body>
<style>
table { 
color: #333; /* Lighten up font color */
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; /* Nicer font */
width: 100%; 
border-collapse: 
collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th { border: 1px solid #00000; height: 30px; } /* Make cells a bit taller */

th {
background: #F3F3F3; /* Light grey background */
font-weight: bold; /* Make sure they're bold */
}

td {
background: #FAFAFA; /* Lighter grey background */
text-align: center; /* Center our text */
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://wcfcourier.com/app/special/data_tables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://wcfcourier.com/app/special/data_tables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1">



$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#five_year').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 300,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#five-year tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#five_year thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#five_year').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
});

} );


$().ready(function() {
    var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;

    $("table td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().match(regEx);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
    });
});
</script>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...." />
  <input type="submit" value=">>" />
</form>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","windows11","main");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY ID asc, Name asc") or die(mysqli_error($con));

echo 
"<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Rating</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Discipline</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Area</th>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Rating'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Discipline'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Rate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Area'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Number'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
// If there is a search variable try to search database
if( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ) {

                $searchq = $_POST['search'];
                $searchq = preg_replace( "#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq );
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Rating` LIKE '%$searchq%';";

                if ( $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) ) {
                    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {

                         echo '
                         <table class="hoverTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Rating</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Discipline</th>
                                <th>Rate</th>
                                <th>Area</th>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>';

                             while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                                 echo "
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>".$row["rating"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["discipline"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["rate"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["area"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["number"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["email"]."</td>
                                </tr>";
                             }

                         echo '
                         </table>';

                    } else {
                        $message = "0 results";
                    }
                }
                mysqli_free_result( $result );
            }
        $conn->close();
?>



</body>
</head>
</html>
```

This is also the Datatables script that works with a HTML table (all the data split out into the table rows using HTML not echo'd out by the PHP script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://wcfcourier.com/app/special/data_tables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://wcfcourier.com/app/special/data_tables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1">



$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#five_year').dataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 300,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    });
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#five-year tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#five_year thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#five_year').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
});

} );


$().ready(function() {
    var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;

    $("table td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().match(regEx);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
    });
});
</script>
```

I can see that this datatables code needs a table ID to reference, but i can't assign a table ID to the  PHP code as it just crashes the script and page when i try.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes it's possible, check [datatables](http://datatables.net/) it has all the intell you need to do that..

Comment: Although, depending on the volume of data, you may want to set-up a MyISAM table with specific fields for the type of data stored there and link to the original records for speed.  Assuming you want to search anything across millions of records asynchronously.

Comment: I've looked at datatables but can't see how to implement this with my tables..

on the orignal HTML tables, i was able to include a table id which then the jscript worked with, but with this way if i add in table id anywhere, it doesn't work and the script crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a simple search on a previous class project that queried a table in my database and returned the results.  You can modify this and give this a try if you think it might help:

Place the search into a form.

```
// If there is a search variable try to search database
```

if( isset( $_POST['search'] ) ) {

```
                $searchq = $_POST['search'];
                $searchq = preg_replace( "#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq );
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Customers` WHERE `Client` LIKE '%$searchq%';";

                if ( $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql ) ) {
                    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {

                         echo '
                         <table class="hoverTable">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Rating</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Discipline</th>
                                <th>Rate</th>
                                <th>Area</th>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>';

                             while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                                 echo "
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>".$row["rating"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["discipline"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["rate"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["area"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["zipcode"]."</td>
                                    <td>".$row["email"]."</td>
                                </tr>";
                             }

                         echo '
                         </table>';

                    } else {
                        $message = "0 results";
                    }
                }
                mysqli_free_result( $result );
            }
        $conn->close();
```

?>

Comment: Would this require the search to be a new page? I need the search to be on the same page as the table, also i'm quite new to this, if this is to work on the same page, where would i need to insert it in my code? if I insert anything in the <?php code it breaks the code and i get a error 500.

Comment: You can run it on the same page.  Just echo the results out into the table you already have set up.

Comment: HI Tony, where ever i insert this code, it just breaks the database code, i've inserted at the bottom, after the mysqli_close($con) line, and it causes a 500 error, i've tried putting it before, at the top, in the middle, in its onw <?php ?> tags and it just causes a 500 error each time. Any suggestions? thanks in advace

Comment: see the edited code.  change the db entities to match yours, i.e. uname, etc.

Comment: the form goes BEFORE your initial php tag

Comment: thanks for the updated code, i've dropped this into my page and its not causing any error's and i've changed the SELECT * FROM Database etc to

SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'Rating' LIKE '%$searchq%' 

to match my database and have also changed the form action to =index.php.

The search doesn't return any results. should the PHP code be a on a new page or should i have the action pointing to a results page?

Comment: Is it returning the results you want?

Comment: I think you're echoing the wrong table columns.  Didn't you have uxxxx as your column names?

Comment: Hi Tony i've updated my code to echo out the correct table names, but when I click the submit on search, i just reloads the page and doesn't return any results. I've updated my code above to show what i've got. thanks

Comment: <tr>
    <td>".$row["urating"]."</td>
     <td>".$row["uname"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["udiscipline"]."</td>
       <td>".$row["urate"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["uarea"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["uzipcode"]."</td>
       <td>".$row["uemail"]."</td>
</tr>";  Are these your column names?